# Why does my script returns Memory Error?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to do a statistics about one web page. This page has categories and products in there. I don't download informations about this products, I'm only counting them.

The point is that I'm getting either `Memory Error` error or just `Some text like Script ends with code -1073741819` (the number is exact).

I've tried to print `size` of variable `category_urls` after each loop and it does not increases.

**EDIT:**
The memory error raises when the category which is being counted is too big (about 60 000 urls).

The main loop is simple:

```
for category in categories:
    count_category(category)
```

I suppose that after each iteration, the memory should be released but I can't see any release when I look at `Task Manager` -> `Memory` tab (Python.exe). I see that the memory consumption is higher and higher.

In case it helps to solve the problem:

```
def count_category(url):
    category_urls = list(get_category_urls(url))
    mLib.printToFile('database/count.txt',str(len(category_urls)))
    set_spracovanie_kategorie(url) # This fnc just writes category url into text file

def get_category_urls(url):
    log('Getting category urls: {}'.format(url))
    urls = []
    next_url = url

    i=1
    while next_url:
        root = load_root(next_url)
        urls.extend(get_products_on_page(root))
        for x in urls:
            if 'weballow' in x:
                yield x
        next_url = next_page(root, url) (next page is defined below)
        # if next_url == False:
        #     return urls
        i+=1

def get_products_on_page(root):
    hrefs = root.xpath('//div[@id="product-contain"]//h2/a/@href')
    return hrefs
```

**AND LXML LOADING FUNCTIONS:**

```
class RedirectException(Exception):
    pass

def load_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=False)
    if r.status_code == 301:
        raise RedirectException
    html = r.text
    return html

def load_root(url):
    html = load_url(url)
    return etree.fromstring(html, etree.HTMLParser())
```

**NEXT PAGE:**

```
def next_page(root, url):
    next = root.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href')
    if len(next) > 0:
        return urljoin(url, next[0])
    return False
```

Could you give me and advice what to do?

Comment: what if batch iteration ? by a range

Comment: Why do you do `urls.extend` and not just `urls = `? With the former you also yield the same url multiple times.